# Calculate min, max and average packet loss

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have metrics sent to prometheus in the form:

```
interface_stats{type="rx_dropped", device="eth0", host="host0.my.net"} 5 
interface_stats{type="rx_packets", device="eth0", host="host0.my.net"} 1000
interface_stats{type="rx_dropped", device="eth0", host="host1.my.net"} 3
interface_stats{type="rx_packets", device="eth0", host="host1.my.net"} 2000
interface_stats{type="rx_dropped", device="eth0", host="host2.my.net"} 9
interface_stats{type="rx_packets", device="eth0", host="host2.my.net"} 1000
.
.
.
interface_stats{type="rx_dropped", device="eth0", host="host325.my.net"} 12
interface_stats{type="rx_packets", device="eth0", host="host235.my.net"} 1000
```

I would like to calculate and display min, max and average packet loss for eth0 over time for all my hosts. All values are counters.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following PromQL query returns packet loss over the last 5 minutes (see `5m` in square brackets) per each `(device, host)` if `interface_stats` is a [counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter):

```
rate(interface_stats{type="rx_dropped"}[5m])
  / ignoring(type)
rate(interface_stats{type="rx_packets"}[5m])
```

You can increase `5m` to `1h` or to any other [supported time duration](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-durations) in order to get the packet loss over the given time duration.

If you need to get packet loss for a particular `device` and/or `host`, then just add the corresponding filter into curly braces. For example, the following query returns packet loss only for `device="eth0"` per each `host`:

```
rate(interface_stats{type="rx_dropped",device="eth0"}[5m])
  / ignoring(type)
rate(interface_stats{type="rx_packets",device="eth0"}[5m])
```

If you need to get the average, max or min packet loss across hosts, then just wrap the query above into `avg()`, `max()` or `min()` [aggregate functions](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#aggregate-functions). For example, the following query returns the average packet loss across all the hosts for `device="eth0"` over the last 5 minutes:

```
avg(
  rate(interface_stats{type="rx_dropped",device="eth0"}[5m])
    / ignoring(type)
  rate(interface_stats{type="rx_packets",device="eth0"}[5m])
)
```